# ln: failed to create symbolic link : File exists

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Can we create a symbolic link to existing directory?

Example: I want to create a symlink from /var/logs to /dump/logs (/dump/logs is exiting directory)
if i do `ln -s /var/logs /dump/logs` i get below error

ln: failed to create symbolic link '/dump/logs': File exists

Comment: Do you want a symbolic link named `/var/logs` pointing to `/dump/logs` or the other way round?

Comment: I want to point all the content of /var/logs to /dump/logs.. In short when i do ls -l /dump/logs - this should show the content of /var/logs..

Comment: Make sure that there are no existing /dump/logs "hard" directories

Answer (score 3):

The existent one goes first before the link name:

```
ln -s /dump/logs /var/logs
```